# Can I use mldivide “\” on an nD matrix without using for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-inverse

Could I use `mldivide` (`\`) on an n-dimensional matrix in MATLAB without using `for` loops? For example, if I have `X=rand (5,5,2,3,6)` and `Y=[0;0;0;0;1];`, can I slice every 5*5 array along the other dimensions to solve it against `Y`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of **Bruno Luong** and his multisolver found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24260-multiple-same-size-linear-solver). The code below can solve any number of dimensions, considering the first two dimensions are of the same size.

```
M=rand(5,5,2,3,6);
RHS=[0;0;0;0;1];
sx = size(M);
sy = size(RHS);
dx = ndims(M);
MSOL=MultiSolver(reshape(M,sx(1),sx(2),[]),RHS);
MSOL = reshape(MSOL, [sx(2) sy(2) sx(3:dx)]);
```